# How to access request.META in a template custom tag in django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I built a custom template tag and I wanna know if there is a way to access `request.META` in my template tag function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your tag to accept `context`, then access `request` by `context`. For example for [Simple tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags):

```
@register.simple_tag(takes_context=True)
def foo(context):
    request = context['request']
    request.META
    ...
```

And ensure `request` is inside the template `context`, by either pass `request` to `Context()` ;or add `'django.core.context_processors.request'` to `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in settings and use `RequestContext` for rendering.

Also, you could simply pass `request.META` to `Context()`